# Map *.domain.com to a single address

Tags: dns, subdomain

I´m not sure if this is really a programming question, but it's related to what I'm doing which is... I'm developing a web site that will have a lot of .domain.com, and based on what  contain, the web site will show diffrent content.

Anyone knows how to do that? Maybe it requires changes in the DNS server.

Comment: You could probably rephrase this in a way to make it a programming question...as in, 'I'm building a web site I want to make available using a custom subdomain. What steps do I need to do that with DNS, IIS/Apache and my code?"

Comment: it was already closed... thanks anyway!

Comment: I think this was wrongly closed, and if someone reopens it so that someone might post more details I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a wildcard DNS entry to point all of those subdomains to the same IP (the one your web server uses). Then sort it out in your application code which site to show based on the host header.

Answer (score 0):

After you have the DNS entries all pointing to the same box, you can use [Apache virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html) to make them behave and appear as separate web servers, without the overhead of multiple Apache instances.

Answer (score 0):

After setting the dns to point all the subdomains to the same IP, you can also configure Apache to rewrite the url to route the request. (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/rewriteguide.html). That is, if you're into Apache =)